# How can I check if column value same on every row on GridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement

I have a grid view with 10 rows.

After clicking on a button I would like to check and make sure each cell value are the same or not under the  `firstname` column of `gridview`.

If all the cell values are same then call the `changeCellValues()` method.  If any cell value is different then `MessageBox.Show("You cant use your method");`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    string x;
    string y;

    x = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        y = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        if (x == y) continue;
        MessageBox.Show("You cant use your method");
    }
}
```

How can I check if column value same on every row on GridView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `10` rows, change `i < 11` to `i < 10` and start `i` from `1` because you already get the first row's value and store it into `x`.Your way seems correct but instead of displaying the messagebox inside of the loop, you can use something like this:

```
x = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
bool control = true;
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
   y = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
   if (x != y) { control = false; break; }
}

if(!control)  MessageBox.Show("You cant use your method");
else changeCellValues();
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use a `foreash` loop in case the number of rows changes in future.

Comment: @AccessDenied maybe, or you can change 10 to `dataGridView1.Rows.Count`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative using LINQ... grab everything in the column "firstname", remove duplicates using `Distinct`, and then count the number of unique names. (If you have more than 1 unique name, they're not all the same.)

```
var isSameName = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                              .Select(x => Convert.ToString(x.Cells["firstname"].Value))
                              .Distinct().Count() == 1;

if (!isSameName)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You cant use your method");
    return;
}

changeCellValues();
```